# Grab one object using another from the same class using Parse.com

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

im new to the parse.com framework and i got stuck :(
to understand better, here is my User class:

[image: my user class]

now what I'm trying to do is getting the "fbid" string using the known "fullname" string.
using the image above, I have "Palmer Zeke" and i wanna get its fbid, "1453064...".

i tried different samples from parse.com forums but nothing worked :(

i'm stuck with this for like 2 days and i would really appreciate some help.

thanks

Comment: Aside: You should really not fetch the unique primary key (`fbid` here) of an object using other, non-unique properties like `username`.

Comment: thank you for your reply! then what is the best practice? i want to get the user profile picture, so i keep it's id for later retrieval.

Comment: Reference the `fbid` from place to place, and fetch the other properties as and when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jesus, the code i was using was correct, the problem was that the default "User" class, is not really "User". Its "_User" (notice the underline).
adding that, fixed everything.

for future reference, i'm currently using this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"fullname" equalTo:[nearby_users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                //NSLog(@"%@", object[@"fbid"]);
                NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", object[@"fbid"]]];
                NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                [cell.tableview_img setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

nearby_users is my `NSMutableArray` with user's full names;

tableview_img is my `UIImageView` from the tableview

EDIT: 
you should use

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

instead of

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
```

thank you!

Comment: The User/Role/Installation classes are all internal, you should use `PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];`